# AngularJS blank page on Safari iOS but runs fine everywhere else

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I wrote a small AngularJS app that seems to run fine everywhere except in Safari (iOS) where I only see a blank page. If I hook up the phone to my mac and run Web Inspector I can see that there are no javascript errors (in fact the app runs fine and by looking at the DOM I see that scope variables are properly evaluated and replaced in the templates). What I DO see are many CSS errors. If I remove the offending CSS styles (Bootstrap 3) the errors go away yet the page remains blank. I tried removing all CSS and most trivial JS libs to no avail.

I'm using the following JS/CSS (in order of appearance on index.html):

- bootstrap.min.css (v3.3.6)
- bootstrap-theme.min.css (v3.3.6)
- app.css (my own stylesheet which literally has two trivial style definitions)
- angular.js (v1.4.9)
- angular-route.js (v1.4.9)
- ui-bootstrap.js (v1.1.2)
- ui-bootstrap-tpls.js (v1.1.2)
- lodash.js (v4.5.0)
- moment.js (v2.11.2)
- app.js (my own app)

Backend: Node 0.10 (running on a free OpenShift account) with Express v4. Files are served via the static middleware. No manual uploading is being done; deployment happens straight from the git repo after doing a push.

EDIT: Completely removed all CSS but problem persists. App fully works everywhere and still showing a blank screen on Safari iOS.

Comment: I suspect some JavaScript error. How about using Safari's Web Inspector to investigate what's happening on the iOS Safari?

Comment: @ShuheiKagawa as I stated on the question, I've already done that.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. Then how is it blank? 0 width and height, display: none or visible: hidden?

Comment: @ShuheiKagawa blank as in "I can see all the HTML in page view and in the console but none is rendering". Also when I mouse over some HTML in Web Inspector I can see that it is highlighting my HTML buttons, divs, etc on the device as if they were there but they are not being rendered.

Comment: Hmm. Do the elements have styles like `visible: hidden`? Or just not rendered somehow?

Comment: As per the questions and above comments you have chaked all possible ways. Now do one thing if possible keep backup of your project. Then start removing everything one by one untile u get the home page. This way I sure u will reach on yout goal.

Comment: Hey Julian, were you able to find what was causing this issue?

Comment: @SebastianPerez No, I could never find the cause. I just kept going and eventually it worked. I suspect something was wrong with my phone, or maybe that version of the OS. Who knows!